# Не получается обратиться из js к php

Tags: php, javascript

вот код

```
jQuery.post(
        "/mysite/protected/views/appslist/operations/updselect.php",
        {
          ar:chckarr,
        },
        function (data)
            {
                jQuery("#appslistupd").html(data);
            }
    );
```

Сам файл, из которого происходит обращение находится в

```
/mysite/protected/views/appslist
```

Ошибка:

```
POST http://localhost/mysite/protected/views/appslist/operations/updselect.php 403 (Forbidden)
```

Comment: Скажу одно: тут явно где-то ошибка.

Comment: все тут норм, уже разобралась

Comment: @Евгения Форманюк, а что было-то

Comment: @Gedweb, в .htaccess убрала строку deny from all и все спокойно начало работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте `.htaccess`'ы по всему пути расположения php файла.
Возможно где-то есть обработчик, который не даёт выполнить запрос на прямую.

Я как понял у вас фреймворк, скорее всего 403 выдаётся не сервером, а вашим приложением.

---

Если у вас *nix ОС

403 - доступ запрещён, проверьте права на файл.

Под виндой таких ошибок не помню, хотя когда это было...